# How to uncheck the resizable option in Scene Builder

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, builder, scene

The resize checker is checked, and it is greyed out, which means I cannot uncheck it. How do I gain access to uncheck this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Whether a `Node` is resizeable or not, i.e. if `isResizable` returns `true` or `false`, is determined by it's type.

This checkbox simply shows this you, but there is no way to set it.

If you want a `Node` not to be resized as long as it's possible for the parent, set min width/height and max width/height to the same value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have set the values but when i resize the window to be bigger, there will appear a white space. Is there any way to remove this white space and allow the content to move with the mouse when you try to resize the window?